# Character stuck in the bridge

Tags: the-witcher-2

I tried that section where there's a dragon chasing you in the bridge a lot of times but I can't move. I am pressing <kbd>s</kbd> but the character is not moving. Is it a bug?

Comment: Does the 4th comment [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/59167095) helps?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 'S' button not working, look at the last 2 comments [here](http://forums.cdprojektred.com/archive/index.php/t-11024.html). It looks like they have reconfigured the keyboard.

If you get the 'S' key working look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j5CmUT1uho) for a YouTube video and comments for getting over the bridge.

This looks like the most helpful comment:

> Hit ESC immediately when it loads and switch to easy difficulty. Now the tricky part is when you are prompted to run, tap S rapidly for a second or two, then hold S right after. It makes you run at first, then stop, and then run continuously. For some reason the dragon will never catch you that way. Take cover like the video shows from the flame, then repeat the process of tapping S and then holding it.